# How to unserialize data array from database to html format

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, serialization

I have a table in database like below

```
 id |     touserid      |            data                 
  1         2                 a:1:{i:0;s:10:"INV-000001";}                    
  2         2                 a:1:{i:0;s:10:"INV-000003";}                  
  3         2                 a:1:{i:0;s:15:"The Mej Hotel";}                    
  4         1             a:5:{i:0;s:28:"Total Goalsi:1;s:7:"6250000";}           
  5         1                 a:1:{i:0;s:10:"INV-000007";}
```

I want to insert that data to table in html like below

```
 id |     touserid      |            data                 
  1         2                      INV-000001                    
  2         2                      INV-000003                   
  3         2                     The Mej Hotel                    
  4         1                   Total Goals : 6250000           
  5         1                     INV-000007
```

but when I tried using unsenrialize, it's just showing array value like below

```
Array
```

How do I show the data into html table ?

Here's my model code

```
public function getAllNotifications()
{
    return $this->db->get('tblnotifications');

}
```

Here's my controller code

```
$data['notifications'] = $this->Sales_model->getAllNotifications()->result();

    $this->load->view('admin/sales/sales', $data);
```

Here's my view code

```
 <table class="table table-dark">
  <tbody>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">To ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Notification</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <?php foreach($notifications as $notif){ ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $notif->id ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $notif->touserid ?></td>
          <td><?php echo unserialize($notif->data) ?></td>
         </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: what's the output of :- `var_dump(unserialize($notif->additional_data));`? show us.And how' you want to represent it in table? tell us that too

Comment: Hi @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie it's showing array value like this array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "INV-000001" }

Comment: so what output you want to show through this array. Add that into your question

Comment: In database table field called `data`, in view `additional_data` - is it correct?

Comment: why are you storing this kind of data in a serialized manner? why not just store it the way you want it outputted e.g. `Total Goals : 6250000 ` instead of `a:5:{i:0;s:28:"Total Goalsi:1;s:7:"6250000";}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change  `unserialize()` `<td>` code like below:

```
<td>
  <?php 
    $data = unserialize($notif->data)
    echo (count($data) > 1) ? implode(' : ', $data) : implode('', $data); ?>
</td>
```

Rest is good in your code

Comment: if I want to add one more implode, it it can do with just : and then implode ?

Comment: sure, depend upon that data have multiple values or single value

Comment: @Alive If you have `$data` which contains 1 element and the implode glue is `:`, how many `:` do you think you will see?  Please rethink this snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Your field ***data*** in your table is an array serialized so you have to unserialize and loop over your data inside ***data***.

One exemple:

```
    <table class="table table-dark">
    <tbody>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">To ID</th>
          <th scope="col">Notification</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <?php foreach($notifications as $notif){ ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $notif->id ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $notif->touserid ?></td>
          <td><?php echo implode(',', unserialize($notif->data)) ?></td>
         </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```